# SQL Update if sum of selected columns =5

Tags: sql, sum

This *should* be fairly simple, I've searched but am only finding solutions to much more complex issues.

I have a table (AP9) with a number of columns and I want to set another column to 1 if 5 of the columns are also 1

e.g.:

| Pas | ColA | ColB | ColC | ColD | ColE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |

What I have tried, and seems to be close is:

```
UPDATE AP9 
SET Pas = 1 
WHERE (SELECT Pas 
       FROM AP9 
       HAVING SUM(ColA+ColB+ColC+ColD+ColE) = 5);
```

Thinking that `Pas` would be st to 1 if the sum of the other columns was 5

But I get an error

> Error Code: 1093. You can't specify target table 'AP9' for update in FROM clause

Surely this should be a fairly easy process, but I am pulling my hair out!

Comment: If you had 1 column with 5 rows, which you probably should, then aggregates would be applicable. Can the values be only 0 or 1? Why not just add the columns if so? And maybe TAG your RDBMS.

Comment: Something like `update ap9 set Pas = case when ColA+ColB+ColC+ColD+ColE = 5 then 1 else 0 end`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the simplest update would be as follows, assuming you only need to update qualifying rows to `1`

```
update app 
set pass = 1
where ColA + colB + colC + colD + colE = 5;
```

Depending on your RDBMS you could also replace `pas` with a calculated or computed column to always show the correct `1` or `0` value.

Comment: Thanks! I was hung up on using the SUM() feature I didn't think to just add the columns. I did get an error in SQL Workbench that I had to disable 'safe update' but that was easily fixed. @500 - Internal Server Error, Your metod also worked, and possibly better, but took a lot longer to complete (on 1.5mil entries) I will set all to 0 before running several of these methods.

Comment: Yes, it will take time because the expression is not sargable, the engine has to scan every row - hence the comment above that you should have *rows* - storing data in this way as columns violates 1nf; if your data was in *rows* an index could be used to sum the values and performance would likely be orders of magnitude faster. you could possibly use an indexed computed column or indexed view, depending on the RDBMS.